# What are the definitive checks to determine whether or not a user can login?

Tags: active-directory

There are several flags defined in the AD attribute userAccountControl.  However, it isn't clear what the definitive checks are to determine whether or not a user can login.  For example,  does the ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE flag mean that the account is disabled?  The list I have come up with is:

- if ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE != 0, then the user cannot log in
- if ADS_UF_LOCKOUT != 0, then the user cannot log in
- if ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD == 0 and pwdLastSet == 0, then the user cannot log in unless they change their password

Does this sound correct, or are there more checks which need to be done?

References to good web pages would help tremendously.  The stuff I'm finding doesn't seem to answer the question.